# How to wrap a C inner loop in Cython

Tags: c, cython

Python programmer with practically zero knowledge of C/Cython here. Any help appreciated.

### Goal

I would like to replace the outer loop of this C-file with python:

"dummy_outer.c":

```
// Try to convert the c file into a cython wrapped c-file that maintains the state.
#include <stdio.h>  

void do_inner_stuff(int i);

int state = 0;

int main(void)
{
    for ( int x = 1; x <= 10; x++ )
      {
        do_inner_stuff(x);
      }
}

void do_inner_stuff(int i){
    state += i;
    printf("State is: %d\n", state);
}
```

So, I want to have a python file that loops from 1 to 10 and calls the `do_inner_stuff(i)` function from C.

### What I did

1. I created a c-file with just the inner guts:

"dummy_inner.c"

```
// Removed the main function and only kept the state and inner functions.
// Python should loop and call the inner function with the appropriate value.

#include <stdio.h>  

void do_inner_stuff(int i);

int state = 0;

void do_inner_stuff(int i){
    state += i;
    printf("State is: %d\n", state);
}
```

2. Wrote a cython file.

"dummy.pyx":

```
cdef extern from "dummy_inner.c":
    void do_inner_stuff(int state)

def py_main() -> None:
    do_inner_stuff(44)
```

3. Wrote a setup file:

"setup.py":

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

dummy_extension = Extension(
    name="dummy",
    sources=["dummy.pyx"],
    libraries=["dummy_inner"]
)
setup(
    name="dummy",
    ext_modules=cythonize([dummy_extension])
)
```

4. Wrote a compile file:

```
g++ -Wall -o dummy_outer dummy_outer.c -lm -O
g++ -Wall -o dummy_inner dummy_inner.c -lm -O

echo "Running c version:"
./dummy_outer
echo "Running python-wrapped version"
???
```

### Issues

I have two problems.

1. When I try to compile the c file it complains about lack of main (but I don't need main, my python file will have main):

```
$ sh dummy.sh

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

2. When I try to run Cython setup I get an error (I've no idea what's wrong):

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace

ld: library not found for -ldummy_inner
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: I think Cython is for running C code inside Python, not to run Python inside C. If you want to run Python inside C, consider something like [boost::python](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/python/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: I thought what I was trying to do is to run C inside Python? Hm... Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: If the main function is written in C, then it's Python in C. If you want to run C in Python and keep using Cython, then consider using Cython tools to compile. Use `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` instead of calling `g++` directly.

Comment: Read chapter about [embedding and extending python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/)

Comment: I have a program written in C that I need to call from python. I need the C program to maintain its state (e.g. when I call the same C-function twice, I get a different result.). As far as I can tell all of the examples in "extending python" only deal with stateless cases.

Comment: I can't maintain state in Python, because C program maintains 100s of different variables and arrays and also writes to files. So I really just want to replace the main outer loop with python, so I can then call it with python, providing custom arguments for each iteration. Hope this is clear as mud :(

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding but: setup.py will create a shared library which you can import in Python. Step 4 is unnecessary. Instead write a .py script that imports `dummy`

Comment: Compile the C program and invoke it from you Python script?

Comment: @jwdonahue I can't invoke it - because it will terminate and discard all of it's state after.

Comment: @DavidW Yeah makes sense. Not sure why setup doesn't work though.

Comment: Convert it to a DLL.  Load that into your python environment and call into it.

Comment: Do you mean with something like ctypes? How?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, this is simpler than I thought with ctypes.

"inner.c":

```
// Removed the main function and only kept the state and inner functions.
// Python should loop and call the inner function with the appropriate value.

#include <stdio.h>  

void do_inner_stuff(int i);

int state = 0;

void do_inner_stuff(int i){
    state += i;
    printf("State is: %d\n", state);
}
```

"outer.py":

```
from ctypes import cdll
from ctypes import c_char_p

inner_lib = cdll.LoadLibrary("inner.so")

for i in range(10):
    inner_lib.do_inner_stuff(i)
```

Then:

`gcc -o inner.so -shared -fPIC inner.c`

and:

```
$ python outer.py

State is: 0
State is: 1
State is: 3
State is: 6
State is: 10
State is: 15
State is: 21
State is: 28
State is: 36
State is: 45
```

Comment: If you're only interested in being able to call C, ctypes can be pretty nice.  If you're also interested in performance, you might be better off with a related technology like Cython, CFFI, HPy - or see http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/speeding-python/

Comment: Omg I don't know what's happening, now I keep getting:
`AttributeError: dlsym(0x7febb1c07d80, do_inner_stuff): symbol not found` all the time. Same code!

Comment: C++ mangles names (so that overloaded functions have different names for example). One option is `extern "C"`